# My Dell XPS Linux Developers Edition lost my password

Tags: dell, password

So I logged in several times today; SSHed in; sent a file over via SCP. No problems with password.

Then I added a utility to PATH via .bashrc.

Now my laptop refuses to recognize my password. Won’t let me in.

Anyone know why/how this might happen and what I can do to recover?

Many thanks,

LRP

Comment: Do you have root access? Is your drive encrypted in a way that prevents login?  Can you just undo the change you did via .bashrc?  Have you tried using a USB to get access to hard drive to change .bashrc?

Comment: I can only bring up the login screen, so no access to .bashrc. I don’t know how to get root access. I don’t have a recovery USB stick, but I could look into that. Thanks.

Comment: Was able to enter recovery mode. The home directory does not show up when I execute ls. My current theory is that I accidentally lost the PATH environmental variable.

Answer (score 0):

In such a case as this, if the entire drive isn't encrypted in a way that you can't access without your username/password, then one can usually:

1. startup using a USB stick to access the drive where your user information is stored
2. edit the affected files to restore PATH (or whatever was broken--if you have a recent backup then restore what was broken from the backup easily)
3. restart after everything is restored the way you want it

If the drive is encrypted then forget it. Save your system as it is and restore from backup is your only solution.